# Server Error in web application program when running it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications, upload

I wrote web application program in ASP.NET 2010. when run in iis, in web config ,display server error,line 13()Authentication Mode).I don't know the reason.please help me.
this code is:

```
webconfig:
    Line 11:     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    Line 12:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    Line 13:        <authentication mode="Forms">
    Line 14:       <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" timeout="30" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    Line 15:        </authentication>
```

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Comment: pls provide the "specific error",also look for some unclosed tags in web config,or tags repeated multiple times or so.

Comment: I checked, all tag is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying .dll file from your bin folder (in the location of your source) to the folder IIS created for your project. Don't know any reasons why it's sometimes being omitted while deployment

Answer (score 0):

Still you have not posted the exact error of the *"yellow page"*

You can try removing some parameters like

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" timeout="30" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true"/>
```

TO

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"  timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true"/>
```

Then Try removing full authentication Tag

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" timeout="30" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Step by step you can understand the exact bug.

Comment: i remove authentication tag,but know it gives me error in  line 16,i remove line 16,it gives me errors line 22.... i think i should do some setting in iis!!!in the above comment i give yello page error!

Answer (score 0):

You should have .Net 4.0 installed in your system. and Nee to change the Application pool of your Project to .Net 4.0. Currently DafultAppPool.

To change the Values. Select your WebSite in ISS manager, you can see Advanced Settings in right side. click on this change the Application Pool to .Net 4.0.